# Maven: add dependecy also with a specific profile

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, documentum

I have 3 projects:

**myLibProject: has 2 profiles**, "profileOne" and "profileTwo": each profile compile a different jar.

**myFirstProject**: has the jar compiled by myLibProject with "**profileOne**" as dependecy

**mySecondProject**: has the jar compiled by myLibProject with "**profileTwo**" as dependecy.

**It's possible to add myLibProject with a custom profile as depedency?**

myLibProject fragment profile: (it's just a sample)

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>profileOne</id>
        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*prop*</exclude>
                </excludes>
                   <finalName>jarFromProfileOne-${project.version}</finalName>                
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
      </profile>
      <profile>
        <id>compimpl</id>
        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude> 
                </excludes>
               <finalName>jarFromProfileTwo-${project.version}</finalName>            
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
      </profile>
```

myFirstProject has as depency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myLibProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <with-profile>profileOne</with-profile>
</dependency>
```

mySecondProject has as depency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myLibProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <with-profile>profileTwo</with-profile>
</dependency>
```

how can I achieve this result? Of course i know "with-profile" does not exists as option.

I need 2 different jars because Documentum's requirment, I know Maven it's created to make a single jar... so I can't use envirnment vars or scope.

Maven 3.0.1

Comment: Sorry, it's probably off-topic, but of which Documentum requirement about 2 different jar we are talking about?

Comment: Documentum 6.6 (a module needs a jar with impl and a jar with interface) @Miki

Comment: Have you tried to supply same jar with both interface and implementation. I'm pretty sure it'll work

Comment: Check this out -> http://onemanwrites.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/installing-documentum-tbo-using-composer/

Comment: Hundreds of reasons to not do that. Not all it's sandbox and so on. It's also a deprecated workflow. However maybe i just need to automatically install jar while i lunch my 2 profiles, but i don't know how to do that